# ADB2C refresh_token always expires in one day

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-ad-b2c

I've been struggling with adb2c for a while now. In particular the refresh flow. I'm using the latest version of `msal-browser` and everthing works fine, refreshing the token works well. The only problem is that the token endpoint returns a `refresh_token` that will always expire in one day. In this case, a user can only be logged in for a day, after that, the user will always have to re-authorize. Here is an example of the endpoint and what it returns directly after logging in. (note that I have set the `access_token` expire time on 5 mins for testing purposes)

Endpoint:

```
https://{b2c_domain.onmicrosoft.com/{b2c_policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Response:

```
{
    "access_token": "{access_token_hidden}",
    "id_token": "{id_token_hidden}",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1610023338,
    "expires_in": 300,
    "expires_on": 1610023638,
    "resource": "{resource_hidden}",
    "client_info": "{client_info}",
    "scope": "https://{adb2c_domain_hidden}.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation",
    "refresh_token": "{refresh_token_hidden}",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 86400
}
```

When, at some point, the application will try to refresh a token, it will call the token endpoint again. This is what a second response looks like:

```
{
    "access_token": "{access_token_hidden}",
    "id_token": "{id_token_hidden}",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1610023891,
    "expires_in": 300,
    "expires_on": 1610024191,
    "resource": "{resource_hidden}",
    "client_info": "{client_info}",
    "scope": "https://{adb2c_domain_hidden}.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation",
    "refresh_token": "{refresh_token_hidden}",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 85846
}
```

The `refresh_token_expires_in` is not rolling. But that is understandable, the user should not always stay logged in. But, in my adb2c policy the following settings are active:

[image]

I would assume, as I have configured in the settings, the refresh token should at least be active for 14 days. If not, even up to 90 days? I can play with the settings, but it will always give me a refresh_token that lasts for 1 day. Does anyone has any experience with this or has a possible solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Msal-Browser which implements the **code grant with PKCE** in SPA application. For this case, you will get the refresh token which will have a expiry of 24 hours and that is not rolling. After 24 hours you need to go to /authorization endpoint of azure ad to get the new access and refresh token. This can also be also non-interactive flow if the browser has the valid login session.

In the Msal-browser library, If you have configured the session more than 24 hours then you can perform the Silent login with ssoSilent(), it require you to send the login_hint.

Comment: Yes we are the PKCE flow. That's too bad. Is there no way to make the refresh token rolling? How could the authorization after 24 hours be non-interactive, is that trough the hidden iframe?

Comment: in the implicit flow, refresh token use to happen in a hidden iframe, going further 3rd party cookies will be blocked so this is not possible. Still you user the non-interact flow to get the token if user session present in the browser. Not able to find b2c documentation but logic will remain same Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. When user closes the browser and comes back to the app 24 hours after the initial sign in interactive sign in is required. That is bad user experience. Is there a way to make B2C session persistent? Azure AD can stay signed in, why cannot B2C?

Comment: For the security reason they have reduce the refresh token life for SPA application but in the PKCE you have two things to perform the non-interactive flow. Refresh token and browser session. Previously you had only one browser session in implicit flow. 
In the new version of the library, you can ssoSilent, login session available then this will happen non-interactively.

Comment: Ref the Msal-browser documentation for more details about the expose api in the library.

Comment: You call it non-interactive, but you always have to login again after one day right? No matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you think, the [lifetime of the refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-token-lifetime-policies) can be up to 90 days. If you need to configure the lifetime of the refresh token, you should use powershell to create a token lifetime policy, and then assign the policy to your service principal to set the token lifetime.  See:  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes).

---

**Update:**

I just used the Azure AD B2C portal to set the lifetime of the refresh token to 14 days, and then tested it with the [ROPC user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow), and the result was that it did take effect. The refresh token I got was 14 days.

So, please make sure that the user flow that you set the lifetime of for the refresh token is the user flow you are using, which is very important!

By the way, your endpoint is wrong, it should be:

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/{b2c_policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

1. 

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

Comment: But why does ADB2C provide a UI that allows you to configure the lifetime of the tokens? These settings should also work?

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer! The application is a SPA and we are using the PKCE flow. Your answer doesn't apply to our current situation.